# How to write logs from separate package to separate file

Tags: go, logging

Here, I have an app which has multiple packages underneath and I don't want to write the logs into one file. Say for eg:

```
   src/packageA/snmp.go
   src/packageA/http.go
```

I want to write the logs from snmp.go to `/var/log/snmp.log` and `http.go` to `/var/log/http.log`

James

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using beego logs for multiple file, https://beego.me/docs/module/logs.md

Comment: Did you create a logger for each destination file and use that logger in the corresponding .go file?

Comment: I am trying to use logs as global var, so not sure how to do that for every file separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`logrus`](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) it might be useful https://github.com/rifflock/lfshook

Comment: Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

[`runtime.Caller(0)`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) should get you this information. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "path"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    _, filename, _, ok := runtime.Caller(0)
    if !ok {
        panic("No caller!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Calling file: %s\n", path.Base(filename))

    // Without extension
    fname := fmt.Sprintf("%s.log", path.Base(filename[0:len(filename)-len(filepath.Ext(filename))]))
    fmt.Printf("Desired log file name: %s\n", fname)

    // you can now use fname to form desired log path
    logPath := path.Join("/var/log", fname)
    fmt.Printf("Desired log path: %s\n", logPath)
}
```

This example will output:

```
Calling file: main.go
Desired log file name: main.log
Desired log path: /var/log/main.log
```

This is just an example. [Try experimenting with a different integer parameter to `runtime.Caller()`](https://play.golang.org/p/GPsTXW9ZctJ) if this doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesSapam see [my experiment I link to at the end of the post](https://play.golang.org/p/GPsTXW9ZctJ) and see if a different caller parameter value works. You can also do negative numbers (`-1` might work).